# What is confirmation notificaion in bitcoin via block chain API

Tags: api, php

I have used bitcoin block chain API in my website, it works and i updated the db when call back the function call but the problem is that db updated multiple times

my codes are

```
if ($_GET['confirmations'] >= 6) {
    //payment confirmed
    //do some DB oparation
}
```

i want to know in which case the paymnet is confirmed and how could i update DB once.

Thanks